# Object cannot be accessed, is it deleted by another thread?

Tags: android, realm

I have this function which is called when there is any change in Contacts in Phone, Now the problem here is that this code works fine on HTC Desire 620 (KitKat) but crashes on Moto G (Lollipop) and other devices.

Error : **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted?**

Also: **It works fine with Moto G2 if contacts are less like < 500** but if more it crashes!

Logcat details:

1. E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.advisualinc.echo:SwitchService, PID: 16972
2. E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?
3. E/AndroidRuntime:     at  io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
4. E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

My service class:

```
public class ContactsSyncService extends Service {
    public static int count = 0;
    int k = 0;

    Realm realmFresh;
    public static boolean contactUpdated = false;
    ContentObserver mObserver;
    public  Context contextService = ContactsSyncService.this;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                super.onChange(selfChange);
                k++;
             //   Toast.makeText(ApplicationController.getInstance(), "Starting Change: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!contactUpdated) {
                    contactUpdated = true;
                    Logger.debug("Contact Update to start -->");
                  //  Toast.makeText(ApplicationController.getInstance(), "Changing: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FetchLocalContacts.refreshingContactsDB(contextService);
                  //  Toast.makeText(ApplicationController.getInstance(), "Changed:  " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
    }
}
```

The Function called by Service is **refreshingContactsDB()**:

```
public static void parseContactstoContactsDB()
{

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Realm realmFetchFirstTime = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());

            ContentResolver cr = ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getContentResolver();


            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,null,null, null);

            String duplicateName = "";
            String duplicatePhone = "";

            if( phones.getCount() >0)
            {

                final int nameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {

                    String name = phones.getString(nameIndex);
                    String phoneNo = phones.getString(numberIndex);



                    if(phoneNo!=null&&!phoneNo.isEmpty())
                    {

                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("(", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(")", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("-", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u00a0", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202c", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u2011", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202a", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("*", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("#", "");

                        if (phoneNo.length() >= 5)
                        {

                            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicateName)&&phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatePhone))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            duplicateName = name;
                            duplicatePhone = phoneNo;

                            String formattedPhoneNumber;
                            formattedPhoneNumber = parseNumber(phoneNo);

                            realmFetchFirstTime.beginTransaction();
                            R_LocalContactDB rContacts = realmFetchFirstTime.createObject(R_LocalContactDB.class);
                            rContacts.setName(name);
                            rContacts.setPhone(formattedPhoneNumber);
                            realmFetchFirstTime.commitTransaction();


                            Logger.debug("Formatted Contacts -->  Name: "
                                    + name
                                    + " --  Phone No: "
                                    + formattedPhoneNumber);
                        }

                    }

                }
                phones.close();

            }

            realmFetchFirstTime.close();
            // getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate();
        }
    });
    background.start();

}



public static void getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate()
{

    Realm realmServer = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());
    RealmResults<R_LocalContactDB> query = realmServer.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).findAll();
    Logger.debug("Contact Update updating to server -->");

    for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); i++)
    {
        phoneNumberJsonArray.put(query.get(i).getPhone());
    }

    try
    {
        uploadContactJsonBody.put("phone_numbers", phoneNumberJsonArray);

        Logger.debug("LocalContacts RequestJson ---> "
                + uploadContactJsonBody.toString());
        AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactPref(1);

        UploadLocalContactsToServerAsynTask test = new UploadLocalContactsToServerAsynTask(
                uploadContactJsonBody.toString(),
                new LocalContactsSyncCallBack()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void didFinishProfileSync(boolean bool,
                                                     String result) {


                        Logger.debug("Is ContactUpdated FetchContacts --> "
                                + bool);

                        setMatchedStatusToFalse();

                        AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactUpdate(bool);
                        Intent roomIntent = new Intent();
                        roomIntent
                                .setAction("com.advisualinc.echo.fetch.local_contacts");
                        ApplicationController.getInstance().sendBroadcast(roomIntent);
                    }
                });

        test.execute();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    realmServer.close();

}



public static void refreshingContactsDB()
{
    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            realmFresh = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationController.getInstance());

            createCountryDetailsArrayModel();
            R_LocalContactDB rCont;
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String simCountryISO = tm.getSimCountryIso();

            for (int i = 0; i < countryDetailsList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (simCountryISO.equalsIgnoreCase(countryDetailsList.get(i)
                        .getCode()))
                {

                    dialCodePrefix = countryDetailsList.get(i).getDial_code();

                }
            }


            AppPreferenceManager.getInstance().setContactUpdate(false);

            Logger.debug("Contact Update Refreshing Contact Started -->");


            ContentResolver cr = ApplicationController.getInstance()
                    .getContentResolver();

            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

            String duplicateName = "";
            String duplicatePhone = "";

            if (phones.getCount() > 0)
            {

                final int nameIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name = phones.getString(nameIndex);
                    String phoneNo = phones.getString(numberIndex);

                    if (phoneNo != null && !phoneNo.isEmpty())
                    {

                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("(", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace(")", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("-", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u00a0", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202c", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u2011", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("\u202a", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("*", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("#", "");

                        if (phoneNo.length() >= 5)
                        {
                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicateName) && phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase(duplicatePhone)) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            duplicateName = name;
                            duplicatePhone = phoneNo;

                            String formattedPhoneNumber;
                            formattedPhoneNumber = parseNumber(phoneNo);

                            R_LocalContactDB realmResults = realmFresh.where(R_LocalContactDB.class).equalTo("phone", formattedPhoneNumber).findFirst();

                            Logger.debug("Size: " + realmResults);
                            R_LocalContactDB rContacts = new R_LocalContactDB(null, null, false, 0);


                            if (realmResults == null)
                            {
                                i++;
                                realmFresh.beginTransaction();
                                rCont = realmFresh.copyToRealm(rContacts);
                                rCont.setName(name);
                                rCont.setPhone(formattedPhoneNumber);
                                rCont.setStatus(0);
                                rCont.setMatchedWithRecent(true);
                                //   Logger.debug("New Size: " + query.size());
                                realmFresh.commitTransaction();
                            }

                            else if( realmResults.isValid())
                            {

                                realmFresh.beginTransaction();
                                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.getName()))
                                {
                                    realmResults.setName(name);
                                }

                                realmResults.setMatchedWithRecent(true);

                                // Logger.debug("New Size Else Condition: " + query.size());
                                realmFresh.commitTransaction();



                            }



                        }


                    }

                }
                ContactsSyncService.contactUpdated = false;





            }
            realmFresh.close();
            deleteExtraContacts();
            getNumbersFromDBAndUpdate();
        }
    });
    background.start();

}
```

Comment: Could you log the stracktrace and post it in the question?

Comment: i have edited the question please check

Comment: It still doesn't have enough information. Would you please post the full backtrace in the logcat here? Which line in your code is the crash point?

Comment: Sorry for that, the line is :  if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.getName())) in my refreshingContactsDB()

Comment: One more thing, the service keeps on calling continuously and maybe it is causing the crash?

Comment: Have you delete the object elsewhere? With version **0.84**, you can use `RealmQuery.isValid()`, `RealmResults.isValid()` and `RealmList.isValid()` relatively to check if the object is safe to operate on.

Comment: There is no ` if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(realmResults.getName()))` in the code you posted. The only place the `RealmResults` is being used is `Logger.debug("New Size: " + query.size());` .

Comment: sorry, i have added them now

Comment: @beeender please can you take a look?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath I checked the updated source code you posted, it should not crash IMO. Would you please share more information: 1. Realm version. 2. is your service in a separate process?  3. the full adb log with a valid crash 4. the exact code piece which matches the adb log in (2). 5. This would be really good if you can share your project or a minimal project which can reproduce the issue. You can send those information to help@realm.io . thanks!